# Still can't enable the slow query log

Tags: mysql

### Environment

This is my environment:

- System: CentOS 7

  - virtual machine, created by virtualbox, only mysql installed
- MySQL: 5.7.35

  - Setup MySQL by this chinese toturial: [link](https://blog.csdn.net/wohiusdashi/article/details/89358071)
- my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]

# slow query log
slow_query_log=on
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/slow_query.log
long_query_time=1

# UTF-8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8

# disable case sensitive
lower_case_table_names=1

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

I have created the log file and executed these as root:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
service mysqld restart
```

### Problem

**The slow query log is not enabled**

When I try this in mysql as root:

```
show variables like '%slow%';
```

It shows these:

```
+---------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                         |
+---------------------------+-------------------------------+
| log_slow_admin_statements | OFF                           |
| log_slow_slave_statements | OFF                           |
| slow_launch_time          | 2                             |
| slow_query_log            | OFF                           |
| slow_query_log_file       | /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log |
+---------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

### Tried

When I try to enable the query log manually:

```
set global slow_query_log = ON;
```

Error

```
ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/var/log/mysql/slow_query.log' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

others:

- add `general_log=on` under `[mysqld]` in `my.cnf`
- replace `on` or `ON` by number `1`

Did I do anything wrong?
Maybe a simple stupid mistake but I can't figure it out...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the directory ownership is correct, and that its Centos7, you'll need to fix the selinux permission.

The manual entry is [on this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/selinux-file-context.html) using `mysqld_log_t`, the same as the error log, because that will allow logrotate rules to access it.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_log_t /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log
```

Then you should be able to enable, even at runtime:

```
set global slow_query_log = ON;
```

Comment: Gerat, I run these in bash: `yum provides /usr/sbin/semanage` & `yum install -y policycoreutils-python-xxxxx`(xxx is the provided package version) & `semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_log_t /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log` & `restorecon -Rv /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log`, now it works, Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

There are far too many settings to get it right:

```
log_output = FILE
slow_query_log = ON
slow_query_log_file = (fullpath to some file)
long_query_time = 1
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
log_queries_not_using_indexes = OFF
```

More discussion and more options:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog